# MS Visio how to create custom shape

Tags: visio

I need to create a custom shape like that one on figure

[image]

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visio 2013 Pro there is a Developer tool tab that allows you to modify existing shapes to create unique ones. You'll find these commands in the Operations drop down list of the Shape Design section on the Developer tab. If the Developer tab isn't in your ribbon bar, you can make it available by going to the Customize Ribbon section of the Visio Options screen.

Answer (score 2):

the "Developer" tool tab exists in Visio 2010 Pro as well. it seems to be turned off out of the box.

go File->Options->Customize Ribbon to turn it on.

it makes a big difference when trying to build custom shapes.